# How to remove Wubi, without causing boot issues?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, grub2, dual-boot, wubi

I have Windows 7 as my main host OS, and then i installed Wubi Ubuntu 11.04. Later to this i installed a partition Ubuntu 11.10 ( beta 2).

So altogether i have Windows 7, 11.04 (Wubi) 11.10 beta 2

Now basically what I want to do is move some files from the wubi installation via a USB and move them onto the Ubuntu 11.10 partition. And then I want to completely remove Wubi from my PC, without causing any issues with the grub or anything that will prevent booting

Thank you for any feedback guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to Control Panel>>Add/Remove software and remove from there. It uninstalls like any application that you install in Windows. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

In the event that you have a boot problem, Boot-repair can usually sort it out. 
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Spenser If the asnwer solved your problem plases mark it as accepted.

Comment: You could use rsync to back up your data in the Wubi install to external media, then uninstall Wubi as outlined. Then, after you install Ubuntu to a partition, you can import your data.