# I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Wubi, without causing boot issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64832/how-to-remove-wubi-without-causing-boot-issues)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi but I want to know how can I uninstalled without causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To Uninstall the Wubi installation from Windows just go to Control Panel>>Add/Remove software and remove from there. It uninstalls like any application that you install in Windows

In case something happen to the boot then boot from windows cd and in recovery mode type fixmbr that would fix it..

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices :

Either keep wubi installed and uninstall Ubuntu from the program: Open Wubi and click *Uninstall* .That would keep wubi.exe installed at your windows system but remove ubuntu completely.

You can also remove wubi by going to Add/Remove Software which will uninstall wubi and as result, ubuntu as well.